# How to remove a character from a string using baskspace in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, character-arrays

can you give me an example of deleting characters from an array of characters in c?
I tried too much, but i didn't reach to what i want

That is what i did:

```
 int i;
 if(c<max && c>start) // c is the current index, start == 0 as the index of the start, 
                      //max is the size of the array
 {
                i = c;
      if(c == start)
                        break;

        arr[c-1] = arr[c];


 }
printf("%c",arr[c]);
```

Comment: Could you change the title?  You aren't talking about user input events... maybe something like "How to remove a substring from a string in C?"

Comment: This does not work, you need a for loop or memmove. In terms of complexity it has to be O(n).

Comment: @andrewmu ok, changed as you suggest

Comment: @Helmut, but it doesn't work well. It takes arr[current+1] and replace it with arr[current+2], and so on if i press backspace again.

Answer (score 4):

A character array in C does not easily permit deleting entries. All you can do is move the data (for instance using memmove). Example:

```
char string[20] = "strring";
/* delete the duplicate r*/
int duppos=3;
memmove(string+duppos, string+duppos+1, strlen(string)-duppos);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of characters c:

```
char c[] = "abcDELETEdefg";
```

You want a different array that contains only "abcdefg" (plus the null terminator). You can do this:

```
#define PUT_INTO 3
#define TAKE_FROM 9
int put, take;
for (put = START_CUT, take = END_CUT; c[take] != '\0'; put++, take++)
{
    c[put] = c[take];
}
c[put] = '\0';
```

There are more efficient ways to do this using memcpy or memmove, and it could be made more general, but this is the essence. If you really care about speed, you should probably make a new array that doesn't contain the characters you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach.  Instead of removing characters in place and shuffling the remaining characters (which is a pain), you copy the characters you want to keep to another array:

```
#include <string.h>
...
void removeSubstr(const char *src, const char *substr, char *target)
{
  /**
   * Use the strstr() library function to find the beginning of
   * the substring in src; if the substring is not present, 
   * strstr returns NULL.
   */
  char *start = strstr(src, substr);
  if (start)
  {
    /**
     * Copy characters from src up to the location of the substring
     */ 
    while (src != start) *target++ = *src++;
    /**
     * Skip over the substring
     */
    src += strlen(substr);
  }
  /**
   * Copy the remaining characters to the target, including 0 terminator
   */
  while ((*target++ = *src++))
    ; // empty loop body;
}

int main(void)
{
  char *src = "This is NOT a test";
  char *sub = "NOT ";
  char result[20];
  removeSubstr(src, sub, result);
  printf("Src: \"%s\", Substr: \"%s\", Result: \"%s\"\n", src, sub, result);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

string = H E L L O \0

string_length = 5 (or just use strlen inside if you don't want to cache it outside this call

remove_char_at_index = 1 if you want to delete the 'E'

copy to the 'E' position (string + 1)

from the first 'L' position (string + 1 + 1)

4 bytes (want to get the NULL), so 5 - 1 = 4

```
remove_character_at_location(char * string, int string_length, int remove_char_at_index) {

    /* Use memmove because the locations overlap */.

    memmove(string+remove_char_at_index, 
            string+remove_char_at_index+1, 
            string_length - remove_char_at_position);

}
```